# How to change the image size When it is in portrait ratio on WooCommerce

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, woocommerce

I want to set a code that changes the image size of my product image, in case it is a photograph in portrait mode, to a smaller size so that the image fits better on the page. Images in landscape mode look good and should remain the same, but the one in portrait mode are too big. I use WP WooCommerce and Elementor.
Please help.

Landscape ratio is ok:

[image]

Portrait ratio is to big:

[image]

This is what I would like instead:

[image]

[https://jenomajor.com/shop/product/flock-of-sheep-in-fundatura-ponorului/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXKj1.jpg)

I have tried all kinds of media queries, but nothing works.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878)

Comment: Look up object-fit contain.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by doing this:

```css
img{
    width: auto !important;
    max-height: 71vh !important;
    float: right !important;
}
```

but maybe you know better and more clean solution